# Excel VBA search directory and add hyperlink to directory workbooks in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to loop through a specified directory, open excel workbooks that exist in the directory, copy a range from a worksheet and paste the contents to a new workbook.

- In the new workbook, I want to add a hyperlink to the workbook that was copied.
- Here is the code I am using to open, copy, and paste.
- How can I add a hyperlink to the "StrFile" in the last column of my new workbook?

*code*

```
Private Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

' Create new workbook, name file, name sheets, set target directory
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        With NewBook
            .SaveAs Filename:="C:\NewFileName" _
                & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
            NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = ("NewSheet")
        End With

Dim dirName As String
' this is the directory to open files from
dirName = ("C:\TargetDirectory\") 

Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir(dirName & "*.*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    If Right(StrFile, 4) = "xlsx" Then                  ' Filter for excel files
    Workbooks.Open (dirName & StrFile)                  ' Open the workbook
        Worksheets("TargetSheet").Range("A2:AA2").Copy  ' Copy paste to new book
        NewBook.Sheets("NewSheet").Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks(StrFile).Close False    ' Close target workbook without saving
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
StrFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

I have used my code from [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/10382861#10382861) to work with the `xlsx` files directly.

Also I have improved the use of variables to handle the workbooks you are working with

The code would also beenfit from error handling (ie if *Target Sheet* wasn't present etc)

```
Private Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim rng1 As Range


' Create new workbook, name file, name sheets, set target directory
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
   .SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\file" _
               & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
  .Sheets(1).Name = ("NewSheet")
End With


Dim dirName As String
' this is the directory to open files from
dirName = ("C:\temp\")

Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir(dirName & "*.xlsx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
     Set WB = Workbooks.Open(dirName & StrFile)                   ' Open the workbook
     WB.Worksheets("TargetSheet").Range("A2:AA2").Copy  ' Copy paste to new book
     Set rng1 = NewBook.Sheets("NewSheet").Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A"))
     rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
     NewBook.Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(rng1.Row, "AB"), dirName & StrFile, dirName & StrFile
     WB.Close False    ' Close target workbook without saving
StrFile = Dir
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I had tried something similar but was not declaring a range as in your example. I will add error handling, I just wanted to get it working first. Thanks again!